# Missing some Intellisense in VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Alright, I have a problem that's bugging me out. I miss some Intellisense in Visual Studio Code in Javascript files. It works in Visual Studio 2017. I tried to disable all extensions.

[image: Image here]

The left screenshot is VS 2017 and right one VS Code.

Any ideas why it is like this? The property I was trying to access is `preventDefault`. It works, but I kinda need the intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

That's just the difference in an editor and a full fledged IDE.  Visual Studio the IDE will always have more features and intellisense because that's what an IDE is expected to do.  While VS Code is very good, it just isn't an IDE, and does not have the ability to have that deep level of intellisense.  If you need to that level of intellisense for your JS,